# el codigo no funciona en android13

Tags: apk

amigos, el codigo que adjunto no logro que ande en android 13, si me anda con android 7 por ejemplo y android8 no probe con otras versiones aun, pero con el 13 que tiene mi celular no hace nada la app, que me estaria faltando?? adjunto codigo, esta hecho con react native expo, en android 7 corre de maravilla, aprieto el boton start tracking y luego aparece para detener el tracking, tambien envia las coordenadas del movil a mi api, y en segundo plano tambien pero si abro el google maps por ejemplo sino no, hasta ahi todo bien, ahora lo pruebo en android 12 o 13 y no anda ni siquiera apretando el boton de start tracking no hace nada, ni cambia el boton para detener tracking (el tracking no se realiza ni en primer plano ni en segundo) me podran decir si debo actualizar algo para que las ultimas versiones de android lo admitan el codigo?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';

const LOCATION_TRACKING = 'location-tracking';

var l1;
var l2;

function UserLocation() {

    const [locationStarted, setLocationStarted] = React.useState(false);

    const startLocationTracking = async () => {
        await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TRACKING, {
            accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest,
            timeInterval: 5000,
            distanceInterval: 0,
        });
        const hasStarted = await Location.hasStartedLocationUpdatesAsync(
            LOCATION_TRACKING
        );
        setLocationStarted(hasStarted);
        console.log('tracking started?', hasStarted);
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const config = async () => {
            let resf = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
            let resb = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
            if (resf.status != 'granted' && resb.status !== 'granted') {
                console.log('Permission to access location was denied');
            } else {
                console.log('Permission to access location granted');
            }
        };

        config();
    }, []);

    const startLocation = () => {
      
        startLocationTracking();
    }

    const stopLocation = () => {
        setLocationStarted(false);
        TaskManager.isTaskRegisteredAsync(LOCATION_TRACKING)
            .then((tracking) => {
                if (tracking) {
                    Location.stopLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TRACKING);
                }
            })
    }

    return (
        <View>
          {locationStarted ?
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={stopLocation}>
                  <Text style={styles.btnText}>Stop Tracking</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              :
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={startLocation}>
                  <Text style={styles.btnText}>Start Tracking</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          }
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    btnText: {
        fontSize: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        color: 'white',
        paddingHorizontal: 30,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginTop: 10,
    },
});

const sendLocationToAPI = (latitude, longitude) => {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      latitud: latitude,
      longitud: longitude,
    }),
  };

  fetch(
    'https://phoenixtravels.app/api/ubicacionyfoto/648ce27d1e39cdcd3e10010e',
    requestOptions
  )
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
};



TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TRACKING, async ({ data, error }) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log('LOCATION_TRACKING task ERROR:', error);
        return;
    }
    if (data) {
        const { locations } = data;
        let lat = locations[0].coords.latitude;
        let long = locations[0].coords.longitude;

        l1 = lat;
        l2 = long;

        console.log(
            `${new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString()}: ${lat},${long}`
        );
        sendLocationToAPI(lat, long);
    }
});

export default UserLocation;
```